# asp.net sql database write increments SQL seed with zero data going in

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I use a `web.config` to define the SQL Server connection.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ERPConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=HOSTSER\ERP;Initial Catalog=ERPMain;User ID=ERP;Password=Password5*;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The webforms application is published to the internal web server, the database writes go in perfectly on some pc's, but on one specific one, the write adds a seed to the SQL Server database, with absolutely no info going in, and doesn't return any error messages at all and doesn't return a success notification either.

Then immediately on another PC, the write goes in perfectly and the success notification is returned and you can see the seed in SQL Server actually skipped the number of the blank insert... Seeds are then as follows:

```
25561 Purchase Thomas
25563 Purchase Greg
```

The blank seed shows no data at all where the insert was done, but the seed was incremented.

This happens on multiple browsers on this PC, is there some setting I am missing in my connection string in ASP or elsewhere that I am not aware of that might stop this from happening?  I am catching every type of exception and have no error returned to me at all.

Comment: [Stop making assumptions about `IDENTITY`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-making-assumptions-about-identity), stop worrying about gaps - they are really **NOT** a problem! If you have a rollback (a transaction that gets aborted), there might be some identity values that have already been given out - and then not used. Those are lost - **stop worrying about it!** Identity does ***NOT*** guarantee consecutive numbers without gaps - this is ***impossible*** to do....

Comment: This is normal when an error occurs and an inserted record is rolled back. What you should worry about is what's happening to the error message. It seems that there is something in your code that is catching the exception and ignoring it.

Comment: I am not worried about the IDENTITY seed, I am worried as the application cannot be used, because the person on that PC cannot update their deals as nothing gets posted to SQL at all. No update occurs.

Comment: The key is that on every PC it works, except the one. Also, after a restart it works perfectly...then after one or 2 updates, it no loner does anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, it was in my SQL write, unclosed quotation marks, it was only picked up on a specific PC as the person was entering data in Afrikaans, and the language contains many apostrophes. So I have handled them now and the problem is solved. I also wasn't catching my exceptions in an appropriate way, I never tested whether the error actually posted to my error reporting. I first fixed that, then I found the error accordingly.